# What's purpose of initializing a struct as a pointer?

Tags: go, grpc-go, go-zap

Zap initializes its default option struct as follows in [its grpc interceptor](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware/blob/master/logging/zap/options.go#L15):

```golang
var (
    defaultOptions = &options{
        levelFunc:       DefaultCodeToLevel,
        shouldLog:       grpc_logging.DefaultDeciderMethod,
        codeFunc:        grpc_logging.DefaultErrorToCode,
        durationFunc:    DefaultDurationToField,
        messageFunc:     DefaultMessageProducer,
        timestampFormat: time.RFC3339,
    }
)
```

And the [later zap performs a copy of values](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware/blob/master/logging/zap/options.go#L46):

```golang
*optCopy = *defaultOptions
```

What is the purpose of declaring the variable `defaultOptions` as a pointer and then later dereferencing it for copying? I was wondering if there is any issue with not using pointer:

```golang
   defaultOptions = options{
        levelFunc:       DefaultCodeToLevel,
        shouldLog:       grpc_logging.DefaultDeciderMethod,
        codeFunc:        grpc_logging.DefaultErrorToCode,
        durationFunc:    DefaultDurationToField,
        messageFunc:     DefaultMessageProducer,
        timestampFormat: time.RFC3339,
    }

    optCopy = &options{}
    *optCopy = defaultOptions
```

Comment: I can't think of an obvious reason for this, I would be tempted to call it a (minor) mistake, but I'd  be happy to learn why it's not.

Answer (score 2):

My guess, based on previous issues I had with big systems, is that with configuration structs, if for any reason some part of your software changes the value of something, that change will propagate to any function/member who has that pointer, and most of the times you don't want that to happen, you usually want that the configuration that you probably read from a file, stays the same, even if some function needs to do a transformation of a specific field of the struct holding that configuration.

So basically, you keep the original struct fresh, but you can send the pointer around to have its contents copied anywhere.
That's my educated guess, it is most likely an application architecture decision.

Edit: After further pondering:
If the author of the code had in his mind the idea of moving that data structure everywhere in his code, in multiple levels deep and broad, declaring it as value would mean he would have to copy it every time he wanted to move the data from function to function, or that the data structure could be erased by the end of execution of scope, whereas with a pointer he can move only the pointer around (much faster) and then only copy the data once the pointer arrives at the destination function.

Comment: This misses the point entirely. Both versions of OP's code would create a unique copy and avoid this problem with a single object pointed to by multiple owners, all making modifications to it.  A unique copy of the default options could be obtained by `*options = defaultOptions` if `defaultOptions` were not a pointer. But, `defaultOptions` **is** declared a pointer, necessitating indireciton on both sides of `=`, **for no obvious reason**. That is the question.

Comment: OP edited his question after I answered it, providing a new meaning/'point' to the question.
My Point still stands though, if the author of the code had in his mind the idea of moving that data structure everywhere in his code, in multiple levels deep and broad, declaring it as value would mean he would have to copy it every time he wanted to move the data from function to function, whereas with a pointer he can move only the pointer around (much faster) and then only copy the data once the pointer arrives the destination function.

Answer (score 2):

A possible advantage with using a pointer is that you can then have that pointer set to nil; obviously if it is nil, you can't dereference it; but this might be used to indicate that there are no options and there may be code to handle this.

Caveat: I am not a Go programmer.

Comment: It completely misinterprets the question. The question is about a statement, `*x = *y`, where `x` and `y` were declared as pointers, but *there is no obvious reason for `y` to be a pointer*.  If `y` were not a pointer, then the statement could be `*x = y`, without indirection around `y`. It is not necessary for `y` to be a pointer to copy it, there seems to be no obvious reason at all for this.

Comment: The question was looking for a reason to do it this way. I have given a possible reason. When you look at the presented code, yes you are right. However this code is part of a bigger code base. Within that bigger codebase there may be a reason why defaultOptions is a pointer. The question was asking for a purpose of doing this and I gave a possible purpose. So I'm not really sure what your issue is here. I'm just answering the asked question.